# Loop between two Arrays and change values based on condition

Tags: array, vba, excel

Instead of using 45 IF conditions , I put my two ranges into variant arrays.
Then I used the below code to loop between them and change values of the first array `arr1` second elements based on condition.
the first range is only 10K rows and the second range is just 45 rows and code takes about 0.7 second to finish.
I tried to use Application optimizations like (Calculation, ScreenUpdating ,) but it makes no difference on speed.
In advanced grateful for all your help.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
 
Sub LoopTwoArrays2()
 
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
 
   Dim arg As Range, brg As Range
    Set arg = ws1.Range("P2:Q" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set brg = ws2.Range("A2:B" & ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
 
   Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
    arr1 = arg.Value2
    arr2 = brg.Value2
 
   Dim i As Long, k As Long
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    For k = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
 
      If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(k, 1) Then
         arr1(i, 2) = arr2(k, 2)
      End If
 
      Next k
    Next i
 
   arg.Value = arr1
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Greedo mentioned, it is much simpler to write a formula, be that `XLOOKUP` or a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` with fast results and easier maintenance.

However, if you still need to do VBA for whatever reason, then add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime:
[image: ref]

and then use something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
 
Sub LoopTwoArrays2()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    
    Dim arg As Range, brg As Range
    Set arg = ws1.Range("P2:Q" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set brg = ws2.Range("A2:B" & ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant
    
    RangeToArray arg, arr1
    RangeToArray brg, arr2
    
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    
    For k = UBound(arr2, 1) To LBound(arr2, 1) Step -1
        dict(arr2(k, 1)) = arr2(k, 2)
    Next k
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
        arr1(i, 2) = dict(arr1(i, 1))
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    arg.Value2 = arr1
End Sub
Private Sub RangeToArray(ByRef rng As Range, ByRef arr() As Variant)
    If rng.Areas(1).Count = 1 Then
        ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        arr(1, 1) = rng.Value2
    Else
        arr = rng.Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that when reading the values from a range you are not guaranteed to get an array hence the need for `RangeToArray` method.

Also, instead of using:

```
On Error Resume Next
For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
    arr1(i, 2) = dict(arr1(i, 1))
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
```

you might want something like:

```
For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
    If dict.Exists(arr1(i, 1)) Then
        arr1(i, 2) = dict(arr1(i, 1))
    Else
        arr1(i, 2) = Empty 'Or whatever
    End If
Next i
```

which gives you more control on the return value, if the lookup fails.

Answer (score 3):

*(moved from comment as I ran out of editing time)*

---

If you have access to the formulas, something like `=IFNA(XLOOKUP(P1#,A1#,B1#),Q1#)` will probably be faster than anything VBA can do. For the same amount of data you describe it refreshes almost instantly for me*. The formula means *"for every id in P, see if it's in A and grab the corresponding value from B, otherwise (`IFNA`), return the original value from Q"*.

Advanced: If you sort the IDs in A then you can make things Log(N) faster using a binary search in xlookup.

*<sub>If I hold down the F9 key it recalculates at a rate of about 10x per second</sub>